# Confused with the basics of Hash Table in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, output

here is a small code I have written about hash tables.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hashval(int n){
    return n%5;
}


int main(){
    int hashtable[4],num, value;
    for (int i=0 ; i<=4; i++){
        hashtable[i]=0;
    }
    for (int i=0; i <=4; i++){
        cout << "Enter the number you wanna enter : ";
        cin>> num;
        value=hashval(num);
        while (hashtable[value]!=0){
            value=(value+1)%5;
        }
        hashtable[value]=num;
    }
     **// line A //** cout << hashtable[0] << "  " << hashtable[1] << "  " << hashtable[2] << "  " <<hashtable[3]<< "  " << hashtable[4] << "  " <<endl; 

    for (int j=0; j<=4; j=j+1){
    **// line B //**    cout << hashtable[j] << " ";  
    }

}
```

When I enter the five numbers as "13,15,18,29,30", line A displays the output "15  29  30  13  18". However, line B does not display the last element i.e. the output shown is "15 29 30 13 4". Where did the 4 come from?  I am so muddled regarding why the last element is always not printed, no matter what elements are entered, and an element that does not exist is printed instead. Don't lines A and B function in the same way? What is wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your array is too small.

Comment: @BessieTheCow what do you mean? where is it too small?

Comment: @Anon hashtable[4] stores four (4) values. You try to store five numbers into it.

Comment: @gmatht how does it store only 4 values? It stores values with indexes 0,1,2,3,4 , total = 5. also, line A displays all the numbers whereas line B does not, though they are the same code.

Comment: @Anon123 The array only stores 4 values because the array's indices are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: "line A displays all the numbers whereas line B does not, though they are the same code." - Accessing pass the end of an array is undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including your program appearing to work correctly.

Comment: @Anon123 `int array[N]` is an array of size N, the first index of the array is 0. Therefore the largest valid index is `N-1`. A surprsingly large number of newbies are aware of the first two statements, but fail to realise that they imply the third statement.

Comment: Read a   [good book on C++](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see  [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and consider using some standard [C++ container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container); read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `int hashtable[4]` allocates an array that can store four values, with indices from 0...3. However, then you try to store five values in the array.

Usually C++ is poorly suited to the compile and see method of learning. It is very common to compile and test code in C++, find that the code "works", when the code is relying on undefined behaviour. In this case however, we can empirically see that `[4]` only allocates enough space for four elements. The following code divides an size of an array by the size of one of the elements, calculating the maximum number of elements the array can store.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                     
int main(){                                                                                                                     
  int a[4];                                                                                                               
  std::cout << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
  return 0;                                                                          
}
```

The code above outputs `4`, showing that `int a[4]` allocated enough space for 4 elements. Storing five elements in an array containing 4 elements results in undefined behaviour.

While we can end the story there and just say undefined behaviour can do anything, it is sometimes useful to understand (but not rely on) the most common side effects of overrunning an array.  Typically what happens is that you access unallocated memory or memory allocated to another variable. Note that between the 1st and 2nd times you print `hashtable[4]` you allocate the variable `j` and that `j` happens to be 4 when `hashtable[4]` is accessed the second time. It is good bet that since you didn't allocate the memory where `hashtable[4]` resides, the compiler thought it was unused and put `j` there. Then when you printed `hashtable[4]` you were actually printing `j`.

To emphasis that undefined behaviour means you shouldn't rely on compile and test, that is not what happened on my compiler (`g++`). Your code worked fine and it didn't even give any `valgrind` or `-Wall` warnings.

Other that the array being too small your code looks correct to me, so if you just change `int hashtable[4]` to `int hashtable[5]` your code should work correctly on every C++ compiler.